# Derivative/Gradient of log $l_1$ norm

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

As derivative of $l_{p}$- norm is
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}}{||\mathbf{x}||}_{p}
&= \frac{\mathbf{x} |\mathbf{x}|^{p-2}}{{||\mathbf{x}||}_{p}^{p-1}}
\end{align*}

I want to find $\nabla log(||H||_{1})$, where $H$ is positive matrix. So, the chain rule is
\begin{align*}
\nabla log(||H||_{1}) &= log(||H||_{1})' (||H||_{1})'\\
 &= \frac{1}{||H||_{1}}\frac{H |H|^{1-2}}{{||H||}_{1}^{1-1}}\\
 &= \frac{1}{||H||_{1}}\\
\end{align*}

But the answer seems to be

\begin{align*}
\nabla log(||H||_{1}) &= 
 &= \frac{H}{||H||_{1}}\\
\end{align*}

What am I missing here? Where is $H$ at numerator from?

Comment: "Seems to be" answer can't be right even for reasons of homogeneity. The logarithm is essentially 0-degree homogeneous (up to an additive constant) so its derivative is homogeneous of degree $-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the sign function element-wise to the matrix $H$ 
$$S = {\rm sign}(H)$$
Use this to write the Manhattan norm as
$$\eqalign{
\|H\|_1 &= S:H \cr
}$$
where the colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. 
$\,\,A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB).$

Use this to calculate the logarithmic derivative of the Manhattan norm as
$$\eqalign{
\Omega &= \log(\|H\|_1) \cr
d\Omega &= \frac{d\|H\|_1}{\|H\|_1} = \frac{S:dH}{\|H\|_1} \cr
\frac{\partial\Omega}{\partial H} &= \frac{S}{\|H\|_1} \cr\cr
}$$
If all elements of $H>0\,$ then the numerator is the matrix $S=1$ (as you expected). 

In any case, the numerator is definitely not $H$.

Comment: If the log function is $\nabla log(||H||_{1} + \epsilon)$ (where $\epsilon$ is a small positive number), I think the answer does not change?

Comment: @Jan The gradient will change (the "smallness" of $\epsilon$ is irrelevant) becoming $$\frac{\partial\Omega}{\partial H} = \frac{S}{\|H\|_1+\epsilon}$$